# $debounce encounters an error

Tags: angularjs, debouncing

When injecting $debounce in my Controller, I am encountering this Error: Unknown provider: $debounceProvider <- $debounce

```
myControllers.controller('Controller',
       ['$scope', '$compile', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$document', '$debounce','promiseTracker',
   function ($scope, $compile, $rootScope, $timeout, $document,$debounce, promiseTracker) {

       $scope.$watch('newquery', function (newValue, oldValue) {
           if (newValue === oldValue) { return; }
           $debounce(applyQuery, 350);
       });
       var applyQuery = function () {
           $scope.filter.query = $scope.query;
       };
}]);
```

Comment: there is no $debounce service registered. Where do you think it must came from? which module defines the service?

Comment: It might be included in angular 1.3 :https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2690

Answer (score 0):

The native `debounce` syntax is part of the view rather than the controller:

```
ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"
```

since the implementation is:

> debounce is supported natively in angular 1.3 using ng-model-options

The source is as follows:

```
$$debounceViewValueCommit: function(trigger) 
  {
  var debounceDelay = this.$options.getOption('debounce');

  if (isNumber(debounceDelay[trigger]) ) 
    {
    debounceDelay = debounceDelay[trigger];
    } 
  else if (isNumber(debounceDelay['default']) ) 
    {
    debounceDelay = debounceDelay['default'];
    }

  this.$$timeout.cancel(this.$$pendingDebounce);
  var that = this;

  if (debounceDelay) 
    {
    this.$$pendingDebounce = this.$$timeout(function() {
      that.$commitViewValue();
      }, debounceDelay);
    }
  else if (this.$$scope.$root.$$phase) 
    {
    this.$commitViewValue();
    }
  else 
    {
    this.$$scope.$apply(function() {
      that.$commitViewValue(); 
      });
    }
  }
```

**References**

- [angular.js source: ngmodel.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular.js/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js)
- [angular.js Issue #13362: ngOptions is setting select $dirty when options change and selected option is removed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13362)
- [angular.js Issue #14626: ngRepeat breaks when re-created by ngIf under certain circumstances](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14626)